# Not slowing down a loop of tasks, and know when result is returned

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

```
Task<string> RunList(int client)
{
    return pages[client];
}

private async void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        RunList(x);
    }
}
```

This will fly through the loop of tasks, but how do you know when the results are all in without compromising speed of the loop?

Comment: any await or .Wait() will slow it down to a crawl, doing only 1 page at a time, where I'm looking for all of them to start, then notified when all results have been calculated. Errors I should be able to take care of.. Might need some help with Aggregate errors though, I've been stuck there once also.. (InnerExceptions?)

Answer (score 5):

You can `await` on the result of `WhenAll` to ensure that all of the tasks have completed at that point in code.  (It's important not to use `WaitAll` here, that would block the UI thread.)

```
private async void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
    for (int x = 0; x < listBox1.Items.Count; x++)
    {
        tasks.Add(RunList(x));
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

The basic idea here is to simply start the tasks before calling `await` on them.  Here is a simpler example with just two Tasks:

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

This will perform the first task and *then* the second task.

```
var task1 =  Task.Delay(1000);
var task2 =  Task.Delay(1000);

await task1;
await task2;
```

This will start both tasks and then continue on after both tasks have finished, allowing then to run concurrently.

Comment: this seems to only run the very last item on the list 'x' amt of times, why would this be?

Comment: @nobodies That would be a problem with your `RunList` method.  We can't really say since we have no idea how it's implemented.

Comment: await Task.WhenAll(task); should this be await Task.WhenAll(tasks);